# GDB not copting desired string (Buffer Overflow Practice)

Tags: c, gdb

Ok so I am trying to learn about buffer overflows and there is this simple program that is vulnerable of a BoF because it copies the first argument into a buffer of 5 characters. In the source code, there is a function called bar that never gets called by the program. My goal was to overflow the buffer and run that function.

So I loaded it up into gdb and I typed disass bar. the first few lines look like this:

```
(gdb) disas bar
Dump of assembler code for function bar:
   0x0000000000400988 <+0>: push   %rbp
```

So basically, all I have to do is put the address 0x00400988 into the end of the overflowed buffer. I calculated the return address to be 36 bytes past when I overflow the variable.

So in GDB i used the command set args $(perl -e 'print "A" x 36 . "\x88\x09\x40\x00"')

I set a breakpoint right after the strcpy was run and examined what 20 words of rsp looked like:

```
(gdb) x/40xw $rsp
0x7fffffffe240: 0xffffe358  0x00007fff  0x00000000  0x00000003
0x7fffffffe250: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0x7fffffffe260: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0x7fffffffe270: 0x41414141  0x00000088  0xf7a54b45  0x00007fff
0x7fffffffe280: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0xffffe358  0x00007fff
```

My issue is that the return address is not copying correctly. As you can see, it only copies the hex value 88 (and i guess the 00 in the beginning of the buffer.

**This is what I have tried so far:**
I have tried to recompile and check if it was an issue with the address being returned to.

I have tried to change the hex values of the address to random values and that seems to copy. For example, I tried to copy in the values 0x85af4709 into that location and it worked. In fact, I found out that the 09 in the original address is what is causing the issue. For example, I am able to make the address 0x00400788 but it cant be 0x00400788.

That being said, I found out that 07 in ascii is a bell, which can be written as \a. Even if I did that, i got the original issue.

After that, I tried adjusting the amount of "A"s I would copy into the buffer to see if that did anyhting. it didnt.

I even tried to write the string out when typing run in gdb

Then, I googled this issue and found a really good example of exactly what i was trying to do. I used the sample program on page 32 of this article:
https://engineering.purdue.edu/kak/compsec/NewLectures/Lecture21.pdf

To my suprise, exactly what I was doing in my program worked exactly as I intended it to work in the authors sample program.

**As a conclusion,** I was wondering if someone would be able to explain why that one position in the address can contain any hex value except the one I want to copy into it. In addition to that, I wan't to know how I can fix this.

If you would like any additional info id be more than happy to give it to you

Comment: If the buffer overflow is caused by `strcpy()`, or any other string function (excuding `strncpy()`), you cannot copy more than a single zero-byte, because string functions treat `'\0'` as the string terminator. x86-64 virtual addresses must be canonical, so low addresses (normally used for userspace) must have more than one zero-byte.

Comment: I can teach you all you need to know about buffer overflows:  if you write code that cannot overflow buffers, buffer overflow cannot happen.

Comment: @EOF That makes a ton of sense but in that article (the example that works) has a 00 copied (both in the example address and on my computer)

Comment: @yasgur99: Well, you can copy *one* zero-byte easily. Also, if the function you want to ROP into isn't too far away from the original return address, you could just reuse the upper zero-bytes of the original address, since x86 is little-endian.

Comment: @EOF I'm confused. I thought you said I can't copy a 0x00 because that will terminate the string.

Comment: @yasgur99: C11 draft standard `7.24.2.3 The strcpy function, Section 2
The strcpy function copies the string pointed to by s2 (including the terminating null character) into the array pointed to by s1`. The `'\0'` that terminates the source is copied into the destination.

Comment: @EOF ahh Do you mean the 00 between the 4 and the 9

Comment: @EOF how would I reuse the upper zero bytes??

Comment: @yasgur99: Actually, I have no idea what the problem is. `strcpy()`ing `'\x09'` shouldn't be a problem, that's just ASCII `\t`, a `tab`. I'd be more worried about `'\x88'`, since that's not a valid ASCII char, and it's obviously not part of a valid utf8-char in this case. Anyway, on my system the bytes copy just fine.

Comment: @EOF yea I was wondering about that null byte issue. The think that is that the 88 copies just fine! what could it be if it works in your system. that is extremely odd

Comment: I bet the tab is interpreted as an argument separator by GDB, so that ` set args $(perl -e 'print "A" x 36 . "\x88\x09\x40\x00"')` actually has 4 parts - "set", "args", "AAAA...\x88" and "\x40\x00".

Comment: @immibis I think you are right because it says I have three as the argc. how can I fix this issue